# How to fix no SOAPAction header! error

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, axis

Please find below html soap client code which i am using to call my soap endpoint
My  soap webservice is deployed in tomcat as axis project.

Please find below client code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SOAP JavaScript Client Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function soap() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open('POST', 'http://localhost:9090/SMSSoapInterface/services/smsxmlpushservicewsSoap11', true);

            // build SOAP request
            var sr =
                '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                '<soapenv:Envelope ' + 
                    'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
                    'xmlns:urn="urn:mm7pushinterface' +
                    'xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
                    '<soapenv:Body>' +
                            '<urn:SubmitReq>' +
                            '<urn:MM7Version>5.3.0</urn:MM7Version>' +
                            '<urn:SenderIdentification>' +
                            '<urn:VASPID>1234</urn:VASPID>'+
                            '<urn:VASID>12345</urn:VASID>'+
                            '<urn:CampaignName>SOAP Campaign</urn:CampaignName>'+
                            '<urn:CampaignDesc>test</urn:CampaignDesc>'+
                            '<urn:MsgCategory>1</urn:MsgCategory>'+
                            '<urn:SenderAddress>'+
                            '<urn:RFC2822Address >1244</urn:RFC2822Address>'+
                            '<urn:Number>919901251515</urn:Number>'+
                            '<urn:ShortCode >1234</urn:ShortCode>'+
                            '</urn:SenderAddress>'+
                            '</urn:SenderIdentification>'+
                            '<urn:Recipients>'+
                            '<urn:To>'+
                            '<urn:RFC2822Address >6789</urn:RFC2822Address>'+
                            '<urn:Number >919901251516</urn:Number>'+
                            '<urn:ShortCode >7896</urn:ShortCode>'+
                            '</urn:To>'+
                            '</urn:Recipients>'+
                            '</urn:Recipients>'+
                    '</soapenv:Body>' +
                '</soapenv:Envelope>';

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        alert('done. use firebug/console to see network response');
                    }
                }
            }
            // Send the POST request
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', "");
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization');
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('username', 'ecpDemoUser');
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('password', 'ecpDemo');
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', "");
            xmlhttp.send(sr);
            // send request
            // ...
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="Demo" action="" method="post">
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Soap" onclick="soap();" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html> <!-- typo -->
```

Below is the error/stack trace which i am getting when tried to hit soap webservice

```
no SOAPAction header!
       at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.getSoapAction(AxisServlet.java:1013)
       at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:678)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
       at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Below is the soap action present in wsdl

```
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: you should have SOAPAction, you send it empty

Comment: This is been added in client code requestHeader..please refer the client code attached above

Comment: xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', ""); ? it's empty

Comment: In my wsdl soapAction is empty hence i am sending it as empty string. There is no name defined for soap action

Comment: looks like the 'urn' definition does not have a closing quote "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [SOAP 1.1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528):

> The SOAPAction HTTP request header field can be used to indicate the
>   intent of the SOAP HTTP request. The value is a URI identifying the
>   intent. SOAP places no restrictions on the format or specificity of
>   the URI or that it is resolvable. An HTTP client MUST use this header
>   field when issuing a SOAP HTTP Request.
>   The presence and content of the SOAPAction header field can be used by
>   servers such as firewalls to appropriately filter SOAP request
>   messages in HTTP. The header field value of empty string ("") means
>   that the intent of the SOAP message is provided by the HTTP
>   Request-URI. No value means that there is no indication of the intent
>   of the message.

You are using [AxisServlet](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/axis/axis/1.4/org/apache/axis/transport/http/AxisServlet.java) which require soap action

> Technically, if we don't find this header, we should probably fault.
>   It's required in the SOAP HTTP binding.

Code:

```
private String More ...getSoapAction(HttpServletRequest req) throws AxisFault {

String soapAction = req.getHeader(HTTPConstants.HEADER_SOAP_ACTION);
if (soapAction == null) {
    String contentType = req.getHeader(HTTPConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE);
    if(contentType != null) {
        int index = contentType.indexOf("action");
        if(index != -1){
            soapAction = contentType.substring(index + 7);
        }
    }
}
```

..

```
   if (soapAction == null) {
        AxisFault af = new AxisFault("Client.NoSOAPAction",
                                     Messages.getMessage("noHeader00",
                "SOAPAction"),
                                     null, null);
```